# Chromium OpenGL dead project?

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, virtualbox

I've recently started exploring the guts of VirtualBox's Guest Extensions on my Ubuntu Guest. Mostly from curiosity. Partly due to "OpenGL Warning: ... not found in mesa table" warnings. I noticed they are using Chromium OpenGL implementation.  I have a two part question.

1.How do I get rid of those warnings?  Are they indications of a larger problem?  I'm noticing repaint issues which lead me down this path.

2.Am I missing something are is this a 12 year old project last touched 6 years ago!?  Is it being actively developed some where else?  Will it support OpenGL 3?

Online references would be appreciated as I'm having a hard time finding anything other than these below.

- http://sourceforge.net/p/chromium/discussion/stats
- http://chromium.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chromium project is basically dead since 2008 or so. There is no support for GL3.x, and it is not planned. Actually, implementing the main purpose of chromium (application-transparent distributed rendering by manipulating the GL command stream) is incredibly hard to outright impossible with the programmable pipeline and modern GL features.

I'm not really familiar with virtualbox, but I am aware that they just used *parts* of the chromium project to implement a hw-accelerated guest GL simply by forwarding the GL command stream to the host. Such a task is much easier to adapt to modern GL, as no real stream manipulation is to be done. But I'm not aware of how far they have come on that path. So consider this only half of an answer to your question.